# Retrieve data from realtime database into listview

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, firebase-realtime-database

This is my file song.dart

```
class Song {
  final String title;
  final String singer;
  final String cover;
  final String url;

  Song(this.title, this.singer, this.cover, this.url);

  Song.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : title = json['title'],
        singer = json['singer'],
        cover = json['cover'],
        url = json['url'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'title': title,
    'singer': singer,
    'cover': cover,
    'url' : url,
  };
}
```

On the main.dart, this is the code that I was trying to get data from realtime database:

```
  List musicList = <Song>[];
  _MusicAppState() {
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("${getCurrentUID()}").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
      print("Sucessfully loaded the data");
      snapshot.value.forEach((k,v){
        musicList.add(v);
      });
      setState(() {
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      print("Failed to loaded the data");
    });
  }
```

Also on the main.dart, this is the part of code that I was trying to show data into listview:

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: musicList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => customListTitle(
      onTap: () {
        playMusic(musicList[index]['url']);
        setState(() {
          _currentTitle = musicList[index]['title'];
          _currentSinger = musicList[index]['singer'];
          _currentCover = musicList[index]['cover'];
        });
      },
      title: musicList[index]['title'],
      singer: musicList[index]['singer'],
      cover: musicList[index]['cover'],
    ),
  ),
),
```

I don't know why the data didn't load into listview. But the data will be loaded into listview if I remove the `<Song>` in the line of  `List musicList = <Song>[];`. How can I load the data into listview with the `<Song>`? Because I need the class Song in order to build the search function, or any other way that I can build search function without class Song?

Answer (score 0):

Your musicList waiting type Song named class but once the method returns DataSnapshot class. You should firstly convert from DataSnapshot to Song class, if you don't idea how can you convert I'm explaining.

You can try the below line code;

```dart
final musicList = <Song>[];
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("${getCurrentUID()}").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
print("Sucessfully loaded the data");
for(final snapshot in snapshot.value){
    final songModel = Song.fromJson(snapshot as Map);
    musicList.add(songModel);
}
setState(() {});
});
```

Comment: I tried but I got wrong at the snapshot as Map. "The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'."

Comment: I also tried to change from Map<String, dynamic> to Map<dynamic, dynamic> in order for the 'snapshot as Map' work.
I also changed the musicList[index]['title'] to musicList[index].title and so on.
But then no any data is loaded into listview

Comment: Can you try to remove 'as Map' code snippet. Should be view this: 'Song.fromJson(snapshot);' Also, musicList[index].title is right way.

Comment: same, it is loaded nothing into listview.

Comment: You should check 'snapshot' if there are no errors? And musicList length? If these are normal, can you add all code?